# Interface Implementation Philosophy

Tags: c#, interface

In C#, you **are not allowed to** implement an interface like this:

```
public interface ITest
{
    IEnumerable<int> Numbers { get; set; }
}

public class CTest : ITest
{
    public List<int> Numbers { get; set; }
}
```

My question is: Is there some software philosophy that makes this type of implementation wrong? Is it a contested paradigm, sort of like multiple inheritance, where arguments have been taking place for decades?

I can't see any reason why such an interface implementation wouldn't work just fine. If you know about `ITest`, then you only get to see the `IEnumerable<int>` part of `CTest.Numbers`. If you know about `CTest`, then you can use the entire `List<int>` implementation. Since `List<int>` derives from `IEnumerable<int>`, why wouldn't it satisfy the Interface requirements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ability of subclasses to return a subtype when overriding base methods is called [return type covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type)

In this case your example is unsafe due to the setter for the `Numbers` property:

```
ITest t = new CTest();
t.Numbers = new HashSet<int>();
```

If there were only a getter defined in `ITest` then it would be safe, although C# still does not allow it - Java does however:

```
public interface Test {
    Iterable<Integer> getNumbers();
}

public class CTest implements Test {
    public List<Integer> getNumbers() {
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.add(1);
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An interface is a *contract*.  It tells clients *exactly* what methods/properties will be available and *exactly* what types the inputs and outputs are.

When you tell a client that any class that implements `ITest` will accept any `IEnumerable<int>` for the value of `Numbers`, but the `CTest` class will only accept a `List<int>`, you have broken that contract.

If you want to implement the interface but also expose a more specific collection type you can *explicitly* implement the interface, but then you have to decide what to do is a client tries to "set" an `IEnumerable<int>` that is *not* a `List<int>` one option is just to create a `List<int>` behind-the-scenes:

```
public class CTest : ITest
{
    public List<int> Numbers { get; set; }

    // satisfies the interface
    IEnumerable<int> ITest.Numbers { 
        get { return Numbers; } 
        set { Numbers = new List<int>(value); } 
    }

}
```

Now clients that are aware of `CTest` can use the `List<int>` property, but clients that only know of the interface can still set the collection without casting.